# After Updating iZettle SDK 3 in Xcode issue occur

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After updating iZettle SDK 3, shows a error and build failed.
The error is

```
No visible @interface for 'iZettleSDK' declares the selector 'enforcedUserAccount'
```

Error showing on this code

```
 [[iZettleSDK shared]enforcedUserAccount];
```

Project written in Objective-C.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [example]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you search the iZettle SDK on GitHub it quickly becomes apparent that they have refactored this API call into another class - `AccountManager`.

From : https://github.com/iZettle/sdk-ios/blob/d16ed180a20acc36676222a595db0e7863556ed4/Example/Sample/iZettleSDKSample/ViewController.m#L100

```
[AccountManager shared].enforcedUserAccount = email.length > 0 ? email : nil;
```